# What is the base of a subscript called?

Tags: word-choice, typography

In ding<sub>dong</sub>  , "dong" is the subscript but what is the name for "ding"? Base perhaps!

Comment: Script? Seeing as how the others are subscript and superscript?

Comment: @Ronan , I think that could cause some confusion.

Comment: @JasperLocke Oh definitely, that's why I didn't do further research :) But I think "font" could cause problems too.

Answer (score 2):

I think "base" is most likely the best bet. Not only is the (imaginary) line that letters sit upon called the baseline[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) but "base" is also the mathematical term[²](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/subscript-and-superscript-bases).